# 画像がない時表すマークの変更方法（テキストに変えたい）

Tags: php, laravel

例えば「ユーザーが画像を投稿しなかった時」などで画像がない時は、「””」や「代替えテキスト」を入れ込むなどしたいと思っています。
画像だと重くなりそうなので、今回はテキストで考えています。

検索に引っかからず、参考になる記事も見つからず困っています。
条件分岐して, returnで戻り値を設定して表示されると思うんですが、、、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### PostsController.php

```php
    /**
     * 投稿一覧表示アクション
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $searchword = $request->searchword;

        $posts = Post::with(['comments', 'category']) # クエリーの調整
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->fuzzyNameMessage($searchword)
            ->paginate(10); 
        
        return view('bbs.index', [ 
            'posts' => $posts,
            'searchword' => $searchword
        ]);
    }

    /**
    * 詳細
    */
    public function show(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

        return view('bbs.show', compact('post'));
    }
```

#### index.blade.php

```php
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ optional ($post)->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ optional ($post->created_at)->format('Y.m.d') }}</td>
                <td>{{$post->user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ optional ($post)->subject }}</td>
                <td><img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$post->image_file)}}" width="150px"></td>
                <td>{!! nl2br(e(Str::limit($post->message, 100))) !!}
                @if ($post->comments->count() >= 1)
                    <p><span class="badge badge-primary">コメント：{{ optional ($post->comments)->count() }}件</span></p>
                @endif
                </td>
                <td class="text-nowrap">
                    <p><a href="{{ action('PostsController@show', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">詳細</a></p>
                    @can('edit', $post)
                        <p><a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">編集</a></p>
                        <p>
                            <form method="POST" action="{{ action('PostsController@destroy', $post->id) }}">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">削除</button>
                            </form>
                        </p>
                    @endcan
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: view側の話だと思うのでそちらのコードも記載していただけると回答しやすいです

Comment: index.bladeを記載しました。

Answer (score 0):

`$post->image_file` は画像パスが入っている想定で回答します

Viewでimage_fileが空文字（またはNULL）の場合に代替テキストを表示すると良いです

**index.blade.php**

```php
{{-- 省略 --}}
<td>{{ optional ($post)->subject }}</td>
<td>
  @if (empty($post->image_file))
    画像なし
  @else
    <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$post->image_file)}}" width="150px">
  @endif
</td>
<td>{!! nl2br(e(Str::limit($post->message, 100))) !!}
{{-- 省略 --}}
```

Comment: 実装できました！！^^
ありがとうございました。